# PostgreSQL Database connection error

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.1

Hello i am a beginner to postgresql, I am unable to connect Postgresql database on linux system from windows through pgadmin client . I am getting the following error

```
FATAL: no pg_hba.conf entry for host "192.168.1.42", user "postgres", database "postgres", SSL off
```

Kindly suggest me how to do.Thanks in advance

Answer (score 6):

On the db server, edit your pg_hba.conf file and add a line similar to this:

```
host    all             all             192.168.1.42/32            md5
```

If you don't want to use a password (I won't get into the security aspects), you can switch the "md5" for "trust". If you *only* want to allow the postgres user access to the postgres maintenance database, then switch both "all" words with "postgres" (no quotes).

You'll need to reload the config files after making any changes.
Eg.

```
pg_ctl reload
```

or

```
select pg_reload_conf(); -- as the superuser
```

If you don't know which pg_hba.conf file your database cluster is using, if you can connect to any of the databases, issue `select current_setting('hba_file');`

Comment: See http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/client-authentication.html and http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/auth-pg-hba-conf.html for the associated documentation, which goes into further detail.

Answer (score 1):

by default, postgresql deny all connexion if it's not from "localhost"
here is a link for you :
https://wiki.debian.org/PhpPgAdmin